# wpf binding material design dialog width, is either smaller or exceed window width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, material-design-in-xaml

I want set the width of the dialog to cover the entire parent page in this case the UserControland thus the window. For this I tried to bind the width of the material design dialog to the `ActualWidth` of the UserControl.

It worked fine as long as the window is not maximized.

[image]

When it is maximized then the width of the dialog is smaller than the one of the UserControl:

[image]

I have tried to bind the width of the UserControl to the `ActualWidth` of the Window (`Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=win}"`) but it was worst as the dialog exceed the window:
What I am missing?

[image]

TestWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.Views.TestWindow" x:Name="win"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    Title="TestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <local:MyDialog/> <!-- Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=win}" -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MyDialog.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wpf.Views.MyDialog" x:Name="self"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
         MinWidth="300"  MinHeight="300" mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <materialDesign:DialogHost Identifier="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" Height="130" 
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=self}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" Width="130">
            Open
        </Button>
        <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="130" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=self}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Work in Progress" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ProgressBar Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCircularProgressBar}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="16" IsIndeterminate="True" Value="0" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
      IsCancel="True" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        CANCEL
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
    </materialDesign:DialogHost>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: Screen edge]

Comment: I tried binding a custom user control (grid with a label) to the `ActualWidth` property of a `Window` and it works fine for me. 1. What framework version are you using? 2. Is this an issue with the `DialogHost` control. Try it with just a label and see if you get the same result.

Comment: .Net Framework 4.7.2, and I just tried with only a label as a `DialogContent`, exactly the same behavior.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the material-design controls altogether and just use a `<Grid><Label/></Grid>`. This is odd behavior.

Comment: Sorry i didn't got your point, the question is all about the usage of the material design dialog (popup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you would see similar issues if the window were placed next to the edge of the screen in addition to being maximized. The reason is because the DialogHost control contains a [DialogMargin](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.DialogHost.xaml#L17) property that defaults to 35 on all sides. For your purposes, you probably want to set it to 0.

Comment: indeed when i came close to screen edges or even when I slide my window beyond the edges, the dialog went completely [out of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f6kD.png) by the same amount

Comment: I set `DialogMargin =0` it's working fine except that when you slide the window out of the screen the dialog keeps moving to the opposite direction; and  minor point i don't know why when resizing quickly the window, the dialog width is not following/updating fast enough so that we can't  notice the dark layer beneath.